# error al crear array de objetos en un bucle Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, validación, objeto

tengo un problema al crear un array de objetos.
el problema es que solo se deberían crear 2 objetos pero se terminan creando 8 objetos, debido a que cada valor de una propiedad se inserta en un nuevo objeto.
Tengo un array de objetos llamado columnas, que es dinámico ya que los valores y propiedades son cambiantes

[image: Array de Objetos columnas]
lo que necesito es crear objetos dependiendo el valor de la propiedad fila, por ejemplo un objeto que solo contenga el mismo valor de la fila.

```
  ejemplo: [   
    { string1: 'CONTRAPARTIDA',string2: 'NOMBRE',string3: null, number1: 'Orden', number2: 'VALOR ENV.' number3: null},      //objeto con el valor fila=1   
    { string1: 'CONTRAPARTIDA',string2: 'NOMBRE',string3: null, number1: 'Orden', number2: 'VALOR ENV.' number3: null},      //objeto con el valor fila=2
```

con este código trato de crear mis 2 objetos, pero lamentablemente se crean mas objetos de lo deseado.

```
 for(let a in columnas){
 //if(columnas[a].fila ==1) no puedo hacer esta validacion xq como el arreglo columna es dinamico no sé 
 //cuantas filas vengan en el arreglo.  

     arrayFinal.push({
    //valicaciones para hacer coincidir el campoDb con la nueva proiedad del arreglo y insertar el valor
                     string1: (columnas[a].campoDb==='STRING1' ? columnas[a].nombre : null),
                     string2:(columnas[a].campoDb==='STRING2' ? columnas[a].nombre : null),
                     string3: null,
                     number1: (columnas[a].campoDb==='NUMBER1' ? columnas[a].nombre : null),
                     number2:(columnas[a].campoDb==='NUMBER2' ? columnas[a].nombre : null),
                     number3: null,
                     });
```

[image: momento al crear mi objeto]

pero como adjunto en la imagen se crean 8 objetos y solo se llenan una propiedad y lo correcto sería esto solo 2 objetos con estos valores.

```
  ejemplo: [   
{ string1: 'CONTRAPARTIDA',string2: 'NOMBRE',string3: null, number1: 'Orden', number2: 'VALOR ENV.' number3: null},   
{ string1: 'CONTRAPARTIDA',string2: 'NOMBRE',string3: null, number1: 'Orden', number2: 'VALOR ENV.' number3: null},
```

```js
let columnas = [];
let arrayFinal = [];
 
//Arreglo de columnas tipo de dato
let columnaServicio = [
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 1,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "ORDEN",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 2,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "CONTRAPARTIDA",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 3,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "NOMBRE",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7 
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 4,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "VALOR ENV.",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    }
    ]

//Arreglo de información
let val = [
           {
              "Contrapartida": "llgfhfg",
              "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
              "Forma pago:": "FE",
              "No. referencia": 10645124,
              "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
              "Orden": 1,
              "Valor env.": 4.22
          },
          {
              "Contrapartida": "sdsdsd",
              "Fecha de Depósito": 334232,
              "Forma pago": "FE",
              "No. referencia": 33434,
              "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
              "Orden": 2,
              "Valor env.": 444
          }
                ]
                
//bucle para crear un nuevo array con valores de los arreglos anteriores    
    for(let k = 0; k < val.length; k++){
       numbersCount = 0 // CONTADOR DE NUMBERS
       stringCount = 0  // CONTADOR DE STRING
       for(let y = 0; y < columnaServicio.length; y++){
           columnas.push({
           "nombre": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE,
           //"tipo": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO,
           "fila": k + 1,
           "campoDb":  columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO + ((columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO == 'STRING' ? ++stringCount : ++numbersCount)),
                });  
                   }
                    }
// console.log("columnas: ", columnas)
 
 //Aquí viene mi problema
 
 for(let a in columnas){
  if(columnas[a].fila ==1) //no puedo hacer esta validacion xq como el arreglo columna es dinamico no se cuantas filas vengan en el areglo
    arrayFinal.push({
     string1: (columnas[a].campoDb==='STRING1' ? columnas[a].nombre : null),
     string2:(columnas[a].campoDb==='STRING2' ? columnas[a].nombre : null),
     string3: null,
     number1: (columnas[a].campoDb==='NUMBER1' ? columnas[a].nombre : null),
     number2:(columnas[a].campoDb==='NUMBER2' ? columnas[a].nombre : null),
     number3: null,
     });


 }
   console.log(arrayFinal);
```

Necesito alguna solución o recomendacion sobre que puedo hacer o que puedo cambiar de mi código para hacer mas facil lo que estoy tratando de hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro de haber entendido bien lo que quieres, pero creo que puedes conseguirlo de forma más sencilla utilizando un `reduce`.

En la siguiente implementación utilizo un `reduce` para crear un objeto cuyas keys son la fila y los values son objetos como quieres. Luego sólo extraigo los values con un `Object.values`.

```js
const columnas = [
  { nombre: 'ORDEN', fila: 1, campoDb: 'NUMBER1' },
  { nombre: 'CONTRAPARTIDA', fila: 1, campoDb: 'STRING1' },
  { nombre: 'NOMBRE', fila: 1, campoDb: 'STRING2' },
  { nombre: 'VALOR ENV.', fila: 1, campoDb: 'NUMBER2' },
  { nombre: 'ORDEN', fila: 2, campoDb: 'NUMBER1' },
  { nombre: 'CONTRAPARTIDA', fila: 2, campoDb: 'STRING1' },
  { nombre: 'NOMBRE', fila: 2, campoDb: 'STRING2' },
  { nombre: 'VALOR ENV.', fila: 2, campoDb: 'NUMBER2' },
];
    
const resultado = columnas.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
  ...acc,
  [cur.fila]: {
    ...acc[cur.fila],
    [cur.campoDb.toLowerCase()]: cur.nombre,
  },
}), {});

console.log(Object.values(resultado));
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero un poco más de explicaciones lo mismo le ayudaría a entenderla mejor, no crees? No todo el mundo tiene los conocimientos necesarios para entender lo que está sucediendo dentro del `reduce`.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funcionó, te agradezco un mundo, saludos